# Are there buses from Madrid Airport to Gran Via, Calle?

Tags: airport-transfer, buses, madrid, mad

I am travelling to Madrid in July and I'm looking to take the bus from Madrid Airport to Gran Via. I don't want to take the metro as it looks to be too many stops. I'm looking for the easiest/cheapest direct route.

Comment: You mean like a private shuttle? The Madrid metro system is quite good and an excellent compromise between ease of use, speed and price. A city bus is likely to have more stops and be slower. There is an express bus to the [Atocha train station](http://www.aeropuertomadrid-barajas.com/transportation/madrid-airport-bybus.htm), though (I haven't used it). Other options (including taxis) can be slightly faster (traffic permitting) but not cheaper.

Comment: See this site for some extra details http://www.aena.es/en/madrid-barajas-airport/city-buses.html but as @Relaxed states the metro may well be quicker. There are fewer stops on the suburban trains of course depending on exactly where in central Madrid you are aiming for, search Cercanias Madrid for more details and look for line C1.

Comment: Cibeles (the stop on the express bus before Atocha) is a few hundred metres from the eastern end of Gran Via.

Answer (score 1):

> The [Madrid Barajas Airport](http://www.aeropuertomadrid-barajas.com/transportation/madrid-airport-bybus.htm) connects Madrid city centre via urban buses of the Municipal Transport Company (EMT), lines 200, EXPRÉS-203, N27 EXPRÉS, and 101.
>
> Service schedule for everyday of the year: 6:00h to 23:30h. Tickets and fares are available on the [Consorcio de Transportes de Madrid](http://www.crtm.es/billetes-y-tarifas/billetes-y-abonos.aspx).

According to [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Madrid-Airport-MAD/Gran-Via), the line 203 bus takes more than an hour, costs $3-5, runs every 10 minutes from the airport to Cibeles; Gran Via is a 10-minute walk.

Another option is the C1 train, costs $2-$3, 35 minutes from the airport to Recoletos; from there it’s a 15 minute walk to Gran Via.